# Unhandled error TypeError: snapshot.val is not a function when using forEach Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a Firebase Cloud Function, with an `HTTPS` trigger, and I am starting more that one read operation at once using `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)`, when all of the promises are fulfilled the `then(snapshotContainsArrayOfSnapshots)` method gets triggered, and I try to iterate the `snapshotContainsArrayOfSnapshots` with `forEach(snapshot)` method, but I get this Error:

```
Unhandled error TypeError: snapshot.val is not a function
```

Here is the code:
    f

```
let promisesArray = []
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    const promise = db.ref(`/questions/en/${i}`)
    promisesArray.push(promise)
}
return Promise.all(promisesArray)
    .then((snapshotContainsArrayOfSnapshots) => {
        let data = []
        snapshotContainsArrayOfSnapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
            data.push(snapshot.val())
        })
        return JSON.stringify(data)
    })
```

Remember: This ISN'T an `onWrite` trigger so I dont need to call `change.after`.

Comment: Could you add the rest of your code, and in particular what kind of promises you have in the `promisesArray`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are adding to the `promisesArray` are `References`, see doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference)

For each of your references, you should query the data at the reference with the `once()` method (doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once)) and it is the promise returned by this method that you need to add to your `promisesArray`.

So do as follows:

```
let promisesArray = []
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    const promise = db.ref(`/questions/en/${i}`).once('value');
    promisesArray.push(promise)
}
return Promise.all(promisesArray)
    .then((snapshotContainsArrayOfSnapshots) => {
        let data = []
        snapshotContainsArrayOfSnapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
            data.push(snapshot.val())
        })
        return JSON.stringify(data)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I got this warning:
`[2018-06-20T15:44:20.943Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "full" at /multiplayer_games to your security rules for better performance. `

Comment: Refer to the doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data